# (node:23977) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send emails from the site to the post office Mail.ru, but the following error appears:

```
(node:25258) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection.login (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:448:38)
at /home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:271:32
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:215:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:315:20)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1313:14)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/home/user/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
(node:25258) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25258) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And here is the backend code itself:

```
    const express      = require('express');
const nodemailer   = require('nodemailer');
const Parser       = require('body-parser');
const sqlite3      = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const server       = express();

let path_services  = (   __dirname   +   '/public/static/img/services/'   );
let path_html      = (   __dirname   +   '/public/index.html'             );
let path_font      = (   __dirname   +   '/public/static/font/'           );
let path_css       = (   __dirname   +   '/public/static/css/'            );
let path_img       = (   __dirname   +   '/public/static/img/'            );
let path_js        = (   __dirname   +   '/public/static/js/'             );
let path_db        = (   __dirname   +   '/Main.db'                       );

const Body_Parser = Parser.urlencoded({extended: false});



server.get('/', Body_Parser , function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path_html);
});

server.post('/', Body_Parser, function(request, response) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(path_db, sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to Database!');
    });
    db.run('INSERT INTO Client(firstname, lastname, email, phone, message) VALUES($firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $message)', {
        $firstname: request.body.ghostName,
        $lastname: request.body.ghostSurname,
        $email: request.body.ghostEmail,
        $phone: request.body.ghostPhone,
        $message: request.body.ghostMessage
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Good!');
        response.end('Ok!');
    });
    db.close();
    
    let testEmailAccount = nodemailer.createTestAccount();
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:    'email',
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        type: "login", // default
        user: testEmailAccount.user,
        pass: testEmailAccount.pass
      }
    });
    
    let result = transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Node js" <nodejs@example.com>',
      to: "chrome_777111777@mail.ru",
      subject: "Message from Node js",
      text: "This message was sent from Node js server.",
      html: "This <i>message</i> was sent from <strong>Node js</strong> server."
    });
    
    console.log(result);
    
});



server.use(express.static  (path_services) );
server.use(express.static  (path_font)     );
server.use(express.static  (path_css)      );
server.use(express.static  (path_img)      );
server.use(express.static  (path_js)       );

server.listen(8000);
```

I am asking you for help, because I have already visited a huge number of sites (starting with the official documentation and ending with a lot of unfamiliar forums), but everywhere I went it was said about sending emails to Gmail, about sending emails to email was said only in the documentation and on several other sites that copied information from the documentation. I will be very grateful to you if you help!

Answer (score 0):

`nodemailer.createTestAccount` is an async function, that means, you just have to put the await keyword in front of it like that:

```
 let testEmailAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
```

Otherwise `testEmailAccount` is a promise and `testEmailAccount.user` and `testEmailAccount` result as `undefined`.

In your case you also have to make your app.post callback an async function:

```
server.post('/', Body_Parser, async function(request, response) {
  // ...
}
```